# htaccess issue with seo rewritten urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, seo, url-rewriting

I'm having an issue with my .htaccess script which handles seo rewrites that masks php pages to look like directory structures. For example, /contact-us/ would point to contact.php, and /portfolio/ points to portfolio.php and so forth. The script works fine on our Apache 2 dev server, but when I move it to a shared hosting server (not sure of their apache version), rewrites with hyphens work, but the ones without a hyphen do not. I can't even get a copy of the rewrite logs to be able to see where the error is occurring. Here is a sample of my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#Force www link
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

#force trailing slash on files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R,NC]
ReWriteRule ^who-we-are/$ whoweare.php [NC,L]
ReWriteRule ^portfolio/$ portfolio.php [NC,L]
ReWriteRule ^portfolio/web-development/$ portfolio_webdev.php [NC,L]
```

So, /who-we-are/ seems to redirect correctly, but /portfolio/ doesn't. I'm wondering if anyone can spot an error or something I am not doing correctly?

Please help.

Comment: I assume portfolio.php exists and is accessible? Can you access it via www.website.com/portfolio.php ?

Comment: Also, if you swap the portfolio line with the who-we-are line; does portfolio then work (something I have experienced in the past)?

Comment: Yep - portfolio is accessible by typing in www.website.com/portfolio.php as is whoweare.php. Not tried replacing who-we-are with portfolio, but will do so the first chance I get. It's so frustrating trying to debug on a shared hosting account!

Comment: Tried replacing one with the other, but still not working. :(

Edit: Hmm...that's weird, I added $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to the page, and it shows as '/' on /potfolio/ and /awards/, whereas the other rewritten links that do work displays the correct php page name

Comment: I have just uploaded your rules wholesale to my server and they all work for me. Have you removed any rules from your example at all (i.e. to make your example shorter) - I'm wondering if two rules are conflicting with each other?

Comment: I have removed all other entries apart from portfolio to eliminate any conflicts, and I have found something interesting out. If I go to /who-we-are/ it throws a 404 error page because obviously the rule is no longer, but if I type in /whoweare/ it redirects to whoweare.php even though there is no rule for this. I think the same is happening to /portfolio/ - because the redirect name is the same as the php page name it goes to that page. Have you ever come across this?

Comment: Still no closer to finding a solution other than renaming the PHP pages. If anyone can help, please post.

Comment: have you tried removing Options +FollowSymLinks just for a test? this all looks like some kind of cross-file-linking thing to me... or even removing RewriteBase and see if that works at all

Comment: Try "RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*)$ portfolio.php? [R=301,L,NC]".
Or moving this rules before the others...

Comment: Try changing the alias name you're applying to your rule and don’t let it match the php filename it’s mapping to. I'm having the exact same problem and trying to establish if this is an Apache bug or if there's a rule/option that’s missing or causing this. More detail about the issue: The alias you are using matches the actual php files filename. In other words your ReWriteRule for "who-we-are" does not match the filename it's mapping to (whoweare.php) whereas your rule for "portfolio" matches the php filename (portfolio.php).  Try adding the alias as “Portfolio” as a test and feedback pls.